# Розмовляти по мобільному телефону чи розмовляти мобільним телефоном?

Tags: вибір-слова

Як правильно: «розмовляти по мобільному телефону заборонено»; «спілкуватись мобільним телефоном заборонено»; «користуватись мобільним телефоном заборонено» чи є якісь інші варіанти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Розмовляти по мобільному телефону" — правильно.

"Спілкуватись мобільним телефоном заборонено" — ні, тому що спілкуватись можна з кимось або по чомусь (з другом, по Скайпу), але не чимось.

"Користуватись мобільним телефоном заборонено" — правильно, тому що користуються чимось (становищем, руками, автомобілем). У даному випадку мобільним телефоном, тому все вірно.

Comment: Було би непогано навести ӝерела.

Comment: Немає такого слова - "Вірно" . Є правильно. "ГРАМОТЄй"))

Comment: @user2292, слово [вірно](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14682&page=477) є (і в [Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/7624-virno.html#show_point)). Але багато хто справді ввважає, що йому _не притаманне значення «правильно»_. Але [дехто вважає по-іншому](https://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/58465.html).

Comment: @user2292, до речі, Ви можете запропонувати правку до цієї відповіді, натиснувши «edit» — я думаю, таку правку приймуть.